# Cocoapods 1.13.0 not installed properly

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I've been using CocoaPods for years now. When trying to install version 1.13.0 (`sudo gem install cocoapods`), everything works fine BUT after the installation:

- `pod --version` gives me still "1.12.0"
- `pod update` always shows "CocoaPods 1.13.0 is available."

I already removed it completely and did a new install with no success.

I am using Xcode 15.0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you probably have two of them, try:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
```

and then

```
sudo brew install cocoapods
```

to update...

or the other way around

Comment: using brew gives me an error: 

Error: Running Homebrew as root is extremely dangerous and no longer supported.
As Homebrew does not drop privileges on installation you would be giving all
build scripts full access to your system.

Comment: for me the solution was: brew uninstall cocoapods